# Output after sorting?

Tags: java

I am working on making a program that takes a phrase from the user and then puts counts the vowels and then displays all of the vowels in sorted ascending order according to their count.

Example of how it is supposed to look:

```
Welcome to the vowel counter and sorter! 
Enter a phrase!

aaaaaeeeeiiioou

The vowels and their count:

u 1 

o 2 

i 3 

e 4 

a 5
```

I think my code is fine except I really don't know what to do after "the vowels and their count is: after I sorted both the vowels and the counts

```
    int[] vCount = new int[5];

    System.out.println("Welcome to the vowel counter and sorter!\nEnter a phrase!");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();

    String upInput = input.toUpperCase();

    //examine all characters

    for (int i=0; i<upInput.length(); i++)
    {
        switch (upInput.charAt(i))
        {
            case 'A':
                vCount[0]++;
                break;
            case 'E':
                vCount[1]++;
                break;
            case 'I':
                vCount[2]++;
                break;
            case 'O':
                vCount[3]++;
                break;
            case 'U':
                vCount[4]++;
                break;
        }
    }

    char[] vArray = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    //Bubble Sort
    boolean hasSwapped = true;

    while (hasSwapped == true)
    {
        hasSwapped = false; //Assumes it is sorted

        for (int i = 0; i<vCount.length-1; i++)
        {
        if (vCount[i] > vCount[i+1])
        {
            int temp = vCount[i];
            vCount[i] = vCount[i+1];
            vCount[i+1] = temp;
            hasSwapped = true;
            char temp2 = vArray[i];
            vArray[i] = vArray[i+1];
            vCount[i+1] = temp2;
        }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The vowels and their count:");
    for (int i=0; i<vArray.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(vArray[i]+ " " +vCount[i]);
    }
}
```

My output is totally wrong and messed up. I assume you need a for loop to print the array but my output is way off:

```
Enter a phrase!


aaaaaeeeeiiioou

The vowels and their count:

U 1


U 79


U 79


U 79

U 79
```

Please help me print this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment in the code for your sorting:

```
    if (vCount[i] > vCount[i+1])
    {
        int temp = vCount[i];
        vCount[i] = vCount[i+1];
        vCount[i+1] = temp;
        hasSwapped = true;
        char temp2 = vArray[i];
        vArray[i] = vArray[i+1];
        vCount[i+1] = temp2; // this line is wrong. reference vArray not vCount
    }
```

As a note, problems like this are why you should never rewrite sorting yourself. There are libraries for that. It would be much cleaner to implement this using a map of char to int and just output the results based on highest count. However, the below should fix your immediate problem:

```
    if (vCount[i] > vCount[i+1])
    {
        int temp = vCount[i];
        vCount[i] = vCount[i+1];
        vCount[i+1] = temp;
        hasSwapped = true;
        char temp2 = vArray[i];
        vArray[i] = vArray[i+1];
        vArray[i+1] = temp2;
    }
```

Comment: Wow so simple I'm surprised I overlooked that! Thank you nhouser, We just started learning arrays and one of the exercises my professor is trying to get us to learn is sorting arrays using "bubble sort" and this is my first programming class so I don't know anything about maps and libraries!

Comment: @ChrisM No problem, happy to help. Please upvote and accept!

Comment: Will upvote and accept :) By the way, I used my professor's example for the sorting code block, can you tell me why it is vCount.length -1 for the line: for (int i = 0; i<vCount.length-1; i++)

I dont understand the minus one part.

Comment: @ChrisM That would be because you index into `vCount[i+1]`. Since you look at the index `i + 1` you can't go to the full length or else you would try to look at `maxlength + 1`, which would be an index outside of the array. Let me know if that doesn't make sense and I can explain a different way

Comment: I think that makes sense. Because the array maxes out at 5 and you're comparing to vCount[i+1] when it eventually hits a vCount of 5, it can't do vCount[5+1] because that would be 6 which is outside the index so you have to compare it to one less than max so it never goes out of bounds?

Comment: @ChrisM exactly